Geomesa 5.0.0 does not complete ingestion
I am trying to install Geomesa 5.0.0. The versions of the various components I am using are:

Apache Accumulo 2.1.2
Zookeeper 3.9.2
HDFS 3.4
Java Openjdk11

When I try to ingest a shapefile with the geomesa-accumulo ingest command, in the Accumulo Monitor dashboard I see that the file is indeed being ingested.

However, in the shell where I launch the command, control is not returned to the user, that is shell cursor stays busy and it remains stuck on
INFO  No converter defined - will attempt to detect schema from input files
INFO  Creating schema 'gis_osm_natural_a_free_1'
INFO  Running ingestion in local mode
INFO  Ingesting 1 file with 1 thread
[============================================================] 100% complete 1607 ingested 0 failed in 00:00:00
INFO  Ingestion complete in 00:00:03
INFO  Ingested 1607 features with no failures for file /tmp/gis_osm_natural_a_free_1/gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.shp
INFO  Triggering stat table compaction

For the various components, I used working configurations from earlier versions inherited from a stack with Geomesa 4.0.4, Accumulo 2.0.1, Zookeeper 3.7.0, HDFS 2.10.2, and Java 8. I suspect that they are not all compatible with the new versions, but I don't know which component is causing the problem.
No errors are present in the Geomesa and Accumulo logs. How could I try to solve it?

How long did you wait for it to return? It will return once a compaction has been triggered, which may take a little while.

Could you clarify what configurations from an earlier version you're referring to?

The wait was endless, but then I discovered the error. The tserver was giving the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulation.data.stats.StatsCombiner because it could not find the library geomesa-accumulation-distributed-runtime_2.13-5.0.0.jar

This is strange since its visibility was set as it was in Geomesa version 4.0.4. However, moving that library to ACCUMULO_HOME/lib worked. Previously it was placed in the ACCUMULO_HOME/lib/ext folder and its visibility was set in the geomesa-env.sh configuration file via
export GEOMESA_EXTRA_CLASSPATHS=“${GEOMESA_EXTRA_CLASSPATHS:-/opt/accumulo/lib/ext/geomesa-accumulo-distributed-runtime_2.13-5.0.0.jar}”

I suppose some step is missing to make the jar visible where it was located before, although I still don't understand why it worked before the upgrade to Geomesa 5.0.0.

GEOMESA_EXTRA_CLASSPATHS is only used for the CLI tools, and shouldn't be configured to point to the distributed runtime jar. Accumulo uses its own classloading mechanisms.

The Accumulo lib/ext directory is no longer supported in Accumulo 2.1, and the GeoMesa jar needs to be put directly into lib/ (or loaded via namespace install).
